# How to add two arcs together if they overlap

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, angle

I'm writing some code for various calculations with arcs and lines and need help with some math.
I have list of arcs and need to add them together if they "overlap", here is the available variables:
Radius;
Center X Y Z;
**StartAngle;
EndAngle;**
I can check if the arcs have the same starting point and if their radius is the same, meaning we know that they are a part of the same circle. By adding them together I mean I should get a new arc with new starting and ending angles that cover given two arcs.
This could be solved by checking and comparing a lot of conditions but I'm looking for a more mathematical approach.
Few examples Arc{startAngle;endAngle}:
A1{350;340} B1{90;270} -> C1{350;340}
A2{225;20}  B2{90;270} -> C2{90;20}
A3{225;300} B3{90;270} -> C3{90;300}
A4{340;45}  B4{90;270} -> not overlapping

*Edit*
Here is a simple illustration to help in understanding my problem as I'm not the best in using math words.
[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBmjL.png)

Comment: The first thing I would do is recalculate arc parameters to make sure the start angle is less than the end angle (i.e. instead of 350;340 use -10;340). Once this is done, it' will be pretty simple to determine the resulting arc.

Comment: Would it be easier to think about if you had variables StartAngle and Angle and assume anticlockwise rotation. So (220, 40) means 220 to 260. Then combining (220, 40) with (240, 30) becomes (220, 50).

Comment: It's not clear for me. Please provide a graphical example, the most general possible.

Comment: I thank everyone for the suggestions, ended up trying to find all the possible cases and writing a solution for each(probably left out few weird cases where full circle is formed) If anyone has a more scientific or just better approach I'm open for suggestions. Was hoping there is some kind of function or something to help me as dealing with arcs that go through 0 angle is messy. Also, added a simple illustration that maybe will clarify what I'm trying to achieve. And yes, all arcs are in anticlockwise rotation, that's why it's not guaranteed to have starting angle smaller than ending angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider this problem as a problem with subsets of $[0,2\pi)$ (or equivalently, of $[0,360)$ using degrees). Let arc $A=[a,b)$ and $B=[c,d)$ such that $a<c<b<d$. Then $A=[a,c)\cup[c,b)$ and $B=[c,b)\cup[b,d)$ and if we 'add' (take the union) them we get $A\cup B=[a,c)\cup[c,b)\cup [c,b)\cup[b,d)=[a,d)$ which is what we  wanted.

Comment: @vgrmm To add more on top of this, you can also construct arcs that 'pass over' the maximum by considering sets of the type $A=[a,2\pi)\cup[0,b)$. In your examples it could be $A=[225,360)\cup[0,20)$ and $B=[90,270)$ so that $A\cup B=[90,360)\cup[0,20)$ which I think is what you wanted.

Comment: This is probably the best answer I'm going to get, thanks! Also B=[90,360)∪[0,20) does not follow a<c<b<d "rule", it still simplifies the problem but maybe there is a proper solution for such cases?

Comment: That wasn't a rule, just an example. The only rule you have to follow is the 'passing' of the upper bound like in $[225,360)\cup[0,20)$. Rest is solved by using the properties of unions of sets.

Answer (score 0):

Given two arcs A(a0, a1) and B(b0, b1), first make sure the degrees are between 0-360.

Initial test should be to check if any of the arcs form a full circle then of course it's an early overlap.

Otherwise loop 3 times;

First two loop will drag the degrees back in each set so that the condition a0 < a1 and b0 < b1 can be fullfilled. Each time you adjust the degrees accumulate the amount of offset. ie (315, 45) -> (270, 360), offset += 45.

On the 3rd loop if it is still a0 > a1 or b0 > b1 then we had a full rotation/roll over itself thus it's an overlap and the result is (0, 360)

If not then;

Check for condition (a0 >= b0) && (a0 <= b1) || (a1 >= b0) && (a1 <= b1) || (b0 >= a0) && (b0 <= a1) || (b1 >= a0) && (b1 < a1). If true then it is an intersection. Then you can basically define the merged arc M(m0, m1) as:

m0 = min(a0, b0) + offset

m1 = max(a1, b1) + offset

In some cases m0 can be equal to m1 then I basically turn them into (0, 360)

The key point is whenever you add or subtract degrees from arcs, always make sure to normalize them by taking a modulus.

Checking if two arcs are totally containing one an other is a lot easier btw.